# Multisesión en Express

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose, sesiones, express-session

Hola gente buenas noches! Estoy experimentando un problema al crear y manejar sesiones en Express. Lo explico con un ejemplo porque creo que se entiende mejor:

- El usuario A, inicia sesion en la pestaña 1
- luego  el usuario B, inicia sesion en la pestaña 2

Al leer los datos del usuario A en la pestaña 1, obtengo los datos del usuario B.

Es decir que se leen los datos de la ultima autenticacion (usuario B pestaña 2) y este es el problema!
Al iniciar sesion, se crea una nueva sesion que es guardada en base de datos, y luego se envia una cookie con el sessionId. Esto me sirve para buscar la sesion activa y devolverla, pero no logro mantener sesiones simultaneas.

Si alguien me recomienda otro metodo o una solucion a esto se lo agradezco mucho! Saludos.

Comment: Hola, podrias intentar abrir una sesion del user A desde navegador normal y la otra B desde incognito, pudiste hacer eso?

Comment: @Richi Si, de esa manera si funciona! Cuando muestro los datos de ambos usuarios se muestran separados y no se sobreescriben, a que se debe esto ?

Comment: [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) es por pestaña, cookies y localstorage son por dominio ( browser )